# calculations within SQL, how to control it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is more of a high level question as I'm struggling to grasp the concept.

I am building a fantasy league web page which simply shows the results and a league table.  The results are all happily stored in a mySQL table, and my high level thinking is to create the league table WITHIN mySQL so that the web page only has to request a table rather than do any sums itself.

How do i get mySQL to calculate the table? Do i make a separate php file which is then executed whenever i need to update the table? can this all be done within mySQL?

I think i'm confused as my experience is based around a program like Excel that is self contained and auto-updates. in mySQL what initiates the calculation, and can i automate it?

Thanks in advance!
Cal.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the calculations and data that you're going to be calculating please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the fact that the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) can serve the results of an expensive query repeatedly without having to actually re-run the query. The caveat being that the query must be exactly the same and that you must have allocated enough memory that the results stay in memory.

If any tables that are involved in the calculation are modified, the cached query is cleared, so your results are automatically updated.

However, if you don't want to rely on this, and you want to avoid calculations in real time, then you can use an update trigger on the dependent tables and perform the calculations in a stored procedure and update a pre-calculated table.

Comment: ok thanks for the answers all.
So it sounds like there are 2 options: 

1. stored procedures that update a pre-calculated table. this procedure then has a trigger, so in my case i could call the trigger only when i know there is a change.

2. calculate the table every time the page is requested.  This sounds like unnecessary effort if the tables will only update when there is a change (in my case every couple of weeks)?

I appreciate in my case the amount of data we are talking about is small but i want to understand 'best practice' should my ambitions expand!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can select functions of fields as data. For example,

```
SELECT SUM(field1, field2) AS sumOfFields
SELECT AVG(field3, field4, field5) AS averageOfFields
```

Answer (score 0):

Databases' main role is to store data in a way that makes sense.

Business logic (which includes most calculations) should be done after fetching relevant data from the database.

There are some useful database functions that help (alot) when retrieving data, e.g. `SUM()`, `COUNT()`...etc., most of the time it is for reducing the amount of data that needs to be transferred over network.

In terms of excel, think of a table in a database to be like a sheet containing raw data in Excel. Then you will have a sheet or sheets with logic that aggregates and calculates whatever you need from the raw data, these sheets would be separated from the database.

There are still arguments over putting business logic in databases (i.e. Stored Procedures) or outside of it, you can probably see which "side" I am on from my answer, but you should look into the other side of the argument to see which suits you better.

You should probably google up some tutorials about SQL and MySQL to get the gist of what it is capable of.